# SQL Server 2012 Express installation failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 Express on a computer with Windows Server 2012 Foundation, I must recall that this is an Active Directory domain controller but I cannot install the server on another computer.

I have the following error:

> Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.

This is my error log:

```
2015-04-08 15:40:43.55 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (Intel X86) 
    Feb 10 2012 19:13:17 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (WOW64)

2015-04-08 15:40:43.55 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.55 Server      All rights reserved.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.55 Server      Server process ID is 4220.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.55 Server      System Manufacturer: 'Dell Inc.', System Model: 'PowerEdge T100'.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.55 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.55 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.55 Server      The service account is 'NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.55 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2015-04-08 15:40:43.55 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "SQLEXPRESS"
     -m "SqlSetup"
     -Q
     -q "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS"
     -T 4022
     -T 4010
     -T 3659
     -T 3610
     -T 8015
     -d "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Template Data\master.mdf"
     -l "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Template Data\mastlog.ldf"
2015-04-08 15:40:43.75 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 2 cores per socket and 2 logical processors per socket, 2 total logical processors; using 2 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.75 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.75 Server      Detected 4086 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.75 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.83 Server      Perfmon counters for resource governor pools and groups failed to initialize and are disabled.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.85 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 4372 at 08/04/2015 03:40:37 p. m. (local) 08/04/2015 08:40:37 p. m. (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.85 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x00000003:0 Active CPU mask: 0x00000003:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.86 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.87 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.88 Server      Database Mirroring Transport is disabled in the endpoint configuration.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.88 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.88 spid7s      Warning ******************
2015-04-08 15:40:43.88 spid7s      SQL Server started in single-user mode. This an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.89 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.93 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\.
2015-04-08 15:40:43.97 spid7s      2 transactions rolled forward in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:44.16 spid7s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:44.16 spid7s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:44.39 spid7s      Service Master Key could not be decrypted using one of its encryptions. See sys.key_encryptions for details.
2015-04-08 15:40:44.44 spid7s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:44.44 spid7s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:44.69 spid7s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2015-04-08 15:40:44.69 spid7s      Server name is 'SERVIDOR\SQLEXPRESS'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:44.71 spid7s      Failed to verify Authenticode signature on DLL 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\ftimport.dll'.
2015-04-08 15:40:44.71 spid9s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2015-04-08 15:40:44.83 spid7s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
2015-04-08 15:40:44.87 spid9s      The resource database build version is 11.00.2100. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:44.98 spid7s      1 transactions rolled forward in database 'msdb' (4:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:45.09 spid9s      Starting up database 'model'.
2015-04-08 15:40:45.13 spid7s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'msdb' (4:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-04-08 15:40:45.41 spid9s      Clearing tempdb database.
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     Error: 17190, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     Initializing the FallBack certificate failed with error code: 1, state: 20, error number: 0.
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     Unable to initialize SSL encryption because a valid certificate could not be found, and it is not possible to create a self-signed certificate.
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80092004, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support. 
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80092004, status code 0x1. Reason: Initialization failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. 
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     Error: 17826, Severity: 18, State: 3.
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     Could not start the network library because of an internal error in the network library. To determine the cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one in the error log.
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     Error: 17120, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     SQL Server could not spawn FRunCommunicationsManager thread. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows event logs for information about possible related problems.
```

Any clue on what can be happening?

Regards...

Comment: What was in the Windows Error Log?

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade by any chance?  It's kind of acting like an upgrade is taking place.  I mainly say that due to the entries that it's rolling master forward and that it can't execute the commands that create a MASTER SERVICE KEY.  This key uses the Windows DPAPI's to create a unique key for the server that then you can create other keys from.  I haven't noticed this in my installations but I don't install express.  Perhaps Master is just a blank DB that's copied and rolled fwd but figured I'd ask.

Comment: Nop.. im not upgrading, but i do had made several instalation attempts, uninstalling everything before i try to install again... I do Have several errors on the log: Initializing the FallBack certificate failed with error code: 1, state: 20, error number: 0., TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80092004, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support. , Could not start the network library because of an internal error in the network library. To determine the cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one in the error log.,

Comment: Have you tried running the SQLServer service under a different user account ?

Comment: yes... it cannot start

Comment: SQL Server installation is not supported on Domain Controller please don't install SQL Server on DC. Although this is not the reason for failure. The certificate issue is reason for the failure

Comment: SQL is supported on a domain controller, just not recommended for security reasonds, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms143506%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 you just can't run it under a local account

Answer (score 1):

```
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     Error: 17190, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     Initializing the FallBack certificate failed with error code: 1, state: 20, error number: 0.
2015-04-08 15:40:46.82 spid11s     Unable to initialize SSL encryption because a valid certificate could not be found, and it is not possible to create a self-signed certificate.
```

The instance is configured to enforce SSL and SSL is not configured properly. Follow the steps at [How to enable SSL encryption for an instance of SQL Server by using Microsoft Management Console](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316898). You probably want to start by *removing* the `Force Protocol Encryption` option first (which currently exists for this instance in the registry, probably under the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib` the `ForceEncryption` value is 1 instead of 0), confirm the engine starts, then continue from there by either configuring it properly, or removing it if not required.